Use text mode brackets in math mode
I would like to have the same style of brackets in the text mode and the math mode. I use the mathptmx package for the font (Please do tell if there's a better substitute for Times).
As seen from the image, the pair of brackets in ......(2) is in text mode, while those in (2) - (1) are in math mode. I would like to type all brackets in text mode.
Is there a way to force latex to use the text style brackets in math mode without having to type \text{(} every time?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx}

\begin{document}

$9m+n=41$ ......(2)
\begin{align*}
(2) - (1): \quad 8m&=40\\
m&=5
\end{align*}

\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us your short compilable TeX code you have so far!

That is not a good idea as you will loose the ability to enlarge the ()'s (as the text versions does not have the enlarging feature).

It's impossible to help without knowing the font setup you're using. This is some kind of Times, I suspect the obsolete mathptmx. Please, be more specific in your question.

Yes, I use mathptmx. Is there a better alternative to it if I want the Times font?

@matheater https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/newtx/, note that neither uses Times but something very similar. mathptmx should not be used for anything with math.
